# A game-theoretic two-ODEs system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In game-theoretic evolution biology, one can find the following system of two-ODEs describing the population dynamics of two species $A(t)$ and $B(t)$ with time $t$:

$$ \frac{d}{dt} A = \alpha_{AA} A + \alpha_{AB} B + \beta_A A(A+B)$$

$$ \frac{d}{dt} B = \alpha_{BA} A + \alpha_{BB} B + \beta_B B(A+B)$$

I wonder if there is a way to represent the dynamics of this system in closed-forms.

What I do know is that, if all the $\alpha$s are set to $0$, one can get the closed-forms for $t(A)$ and $t(B)$ with the incomplete Beta function.

Comment: Could be, but do you really need the exact solution for any initial condition and for all times? Maybe you are more interested in long-term behavior?

Comment: I'm curious how the solution looks like, in general.

Comment: Just because it looks simple, it may not have a closed form solution. See something similar: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/269332/is-there-a-closed-form-solution-for-fracdydx-1-fracay-fracb The ode system in question is also biologically motivated.